# App running differently from Xcode and device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, debugging, ios6

I have an application that I'm working on debugging.  I'm trying to get it so that it runs on iOS 6.  When I run the application through Xcode using the device as my "simulator", it works perfectly.  But when I download the app from the app store (exact same code), I'm getting a problem loading a menu.  What could the problem be?  Is there anything I can do, or is it just a problem with the Beta of iOS 6?  I can't be too specific because the project is for the company I work for, but I'll answer questions that I can. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with the Beta version of iOS 6.

Answer (score 2):

An application running correctly on the simulator should never mean you assume it will work on a real device. If you have already tried deleting the app from the device, cleaning targets, and reinstalling, then you may want to go back through your code and make sure anything case sensitive is correctly capitalized.

e.x. Instantiating a view controller from a xib named `@"myXib"` if you put `@"myxib"` and forget to capitalized the "X" it will work properly on the simulator but not on a real device because the simulator isn't case sensitive about a lot of things that a real device is.

Comment: That's the thing that's confusing me.  I have my iPad plugged in and am using it to run the application through Xcode.  It works on the device this way, but not when it's not being run through Xcode.

Comment: @SeanSmyth I've run into that before, usually the way to fix it is after running the application to the device from Xcode, instead of just exiting the application from the device, or just unplugging the device, make sure that you click the "Stop" button in Xcode, then launching the app from the device should work.

Comment: I'll try that now and let you know